# Un mot définissant un jugement axé sur une idée de pureté ou d’impureté à connotation religieuse

Tags: vocabulaire

Je pensais à « puritain » parce que je souhaite montrer le parallèle avec l'interprétation religieuse de la pureté (et ses conséquences). *Mais la notion de puritanisme semble rattachée à une connotation d’austérité*, ce qui me dérange (l’est-elle forcément pour vous ?).

Je voulais l’employer pour parler

> « une attitude compassionnelle [puritaine] »

ou

> « d'un jugement [puritain] » (Un jugement sur le degré de pureté moral d'une personne).

pour critiquer une personne dont la compassion s’adresse aux gens qu’elle estime (plus) purs.

Le mot ou l'expression que je recherche pourrait s'appliquer au cas d'une personne qui aimerait les bonnes choses (les bons vins, bonne nourriture, les plaisirs de la vie), mais qui condamnerait ceux qu’elle considère comme impurs (parce qu’immoral pour une raison ou une autre). (L’hédonisme et l’obsession de pureté morale sont parfaitement compatibles).

● J’ai pensé à :

> un jugement [moraliste] :

mais cela focalise plus sur l’aspect moral que celui de la pureté (même si les deux sont proches ce ne sont pas des synonymes).

> un jugement [puriste] :

semble aussi rater l’aspect religieux et semble donner soit une connotation morale, soit une connotation trop superficielle (ex: "les puristes ― du langage ― refusent les anglicismes").

Comment: Ce n'est pas en un mot, mais que pensez vous de "compassion à géométrie variable en faveur des orthodoxes/bon croyants/fidèles/dévôts" ?

Comment: Merci, Pierre, mais le mot que je cherche doit montrer le parallèle avec l’obsession de pureté morale religieuse. Un « jugement à géométrie variable » ne montre pas ce parallèle.

Comment: Ce qui te dérange dans "puritain" c'est qu'on n'imagine pas cette personne comme pouvant aimer les plaisir de la vie ?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps oui tu as bien compris. Mais il semblerait que ce mot ne soit systématiquement rattaché à la notion d'austérité (il le serait pour parler du courant religieux puritanisme, mais pas nécessairement comme adjectif). Donc puritain semble aller. Qu'est ce que t'en penses ?

Comment: @Lisa Je pense qu'effectivement, quand on qualifie quelqu'un de puritain, on l'imagine austère.

Comment: Ca ne correspond pas tout à fait, mais je n'ai rien trouvé de plus proche de ce que je comprends de votre demande: Une attitude compassionnelle clérical. Un jugement ecclésiastique. On a ici l'idée de relativité à l'Eglise, non connoté, mais on comprend toujours que le jugement se fait par rapport à des valeurs religieuse. Cela marche donc si vous voulez parler de religion chrétienne, ou par extrapolation pour toute forme de religion, mais sera hors de propos si vous souhaitez parlé uniquement d'une personne ou d'un groupe de personne appartenant uniquement à une religion.

Comment: Un jugement hypochrist.

OK je sors…

Comment: J'en propose deux autres, pas totalement convaincants, mais qui peuvent faire avancer la réflexion : **pieux** et **manichéen**.

Comment: The following suggestions with religious connotations would hopefully be taken as insults by such a person, and rightfully so for, imo, anyone who [com?]passionately criticizes, whether hypocritically or not, others for being less than “pure” certainly deserves nothing better (& probably much, much worse): ...     “attitude/esprit/jugement/personne/bla-bla  [pharisaïque](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pharisa%C3%AFque) … [Prêchi, prêcha](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prechi) … ou [PRÊCHEUR/EUSE-sense “B”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/precheur).

Comment: Je propose un nouveau mot : "un jugement `puritiste` (ou `vertuiste`)" (ma petite contribution [Non-Copyrighted] à l'evolution de la langue française).

Answer (score 4):

On pourrait penser au mot « pudibond » également. Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pudibond) a par exemple une citation qui montre bien le côté péjoratif de ce mot :

> « Et la gente pudibonde n’a point reculé devant la responsabilité d’actes de vandalisme, comme ceux qui firent draper après coup les beaux corps de Michel-Ange dans le « Jugement Dernier », proscrire les madones offrant le sein au divin enfant, et couvrir de feuilles de vigne les nudités antiques. »
>
> Jean Marestan, *L’Éducation Sexuelle*, Éditions de la « Guerre sociale », 1910

Le [site du CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pudibond) propose également des citations (sens B), parmi lesquelles :

> « Qu'une société, rongée par l'érotisme, soit condamnée, les Soviétiques n'en doutent pas. Nous nous moquons de leur art pudibond et de leur "prêchi-prêcha" officiel. »
>
> Mauriac, *Nouv. Bloc-Notes*, 1961, p. 394

On perd un peu la connotation religieuse de « puritain » en revanche. On aurait aussi pu penser à « janséniste », mais il y a là aussi une notion d'austérité qui ne convient pas.

Comment: Bienvenue sur FSE, pense à mettre des liens et des citations, ça donne plus de poids à tes réponses. N'hésite pas à faire un petit [tour] !

Comment: +1 pour la belle addition, surtout l’inclusion de "prêchi-prêcha", qui va très bien ici, je trouve.

Answer (score 1):

Peut être pourrais tu utiliser le mot « vertueux », qui dans le cadre de la religion signifie « Qui ne commet pas de péchés. »

Comment: « Une approche compassionnelle vertueuse », ou « un jugement vertueux » ne va pas, cela donne l’effet l’inverse : ces formes ne montrent pas la critique sur la religiosité et l’obsession de pureté du jugement (ou de l’approche compassionnelle)